# Gnuplot: line background or foreground

Tags: plot, background, gnuplot, line

I am plotting two sets of data points displayed as lines (smooth unique), one in lighter and one in darker colour. I want to specify which line is shown in the foreground and which, relative to the other line, in the background. One set of data are only covering a small area of the plot, relative to the other. I want to show the line for these data in the foreground, since otherwise it is obscured by the other line (at least in the line thickness that I want for my plot).

It is possible for specify 'front' (for foreground display) for labels and arrows in Gnuplot. I imagined this should be easy for lines too, but could not find any pointers in Gnuplot manuals.

Comment: I don't think that there is a special keyword for that, but merely changing the order of the datasets as they appear in the `plot` command should suffice (the last one will be on top)

Comment: As @ewcz says, the plots are drawn sequentially in the same order as they are specified. `plot f1(x), f2(x), f3(x) ...` will plot f1(x), then f2(x) on top of it, then f3(x) on top of f1(x) and f2(x), etc.